# How can I assign more CPU usage to a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, time, jupyter-notebook, cpu

I am using a shared computer with several CPUs, but when I run a notebook it only uses one CPU. Is there any way I can assign the jupyter notebook to use more of the CPUs available?

Comment: It depends on what your doing. Can you include some code relevant to your problem?

Comment: I am basically running a for loop to compute different integrals. (Yes, there is no feasible way of doing it without a for loop, due to memory usage). I have like 16 CPUs available but the notebook keeps on running in just one CPU.

Comment: CPython will only ever utilize a single CPU. Now, libraries that are written as C-extensions can do whatever they want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to "assign" more CPU power to a task is not associated with Jupyter IDE but rather is a library within python. I would recommend using the multiprocessing library. Please refer to [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) for the official multiprocessing documentation. A sample code is provided below:

```
import multiprocessing


def main(number):
    print(number)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=main, args=(1,))
    p2 = Process(target=main, args=(2,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

You can think of each of these processes as more CPU power being used to perform a task.